# What's the most efficient way to end an infinite-scroll when running out of content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, infinite-scroll

We have a web application where we automatically load more content when we reach the bottom of the page like so:

```
$window
.on('scroll', function () {
    var 
        $this = $(this)
    ;
    if ($this.scrollTop() == $document.height() - $window.height()
        && $('#product-list').hasClass('has-more')) {
        // load more content
    }
})
```

We currently use a 'has-more' class on a parent element that is removed when there's no more content available.

I'm not quite satisfied with the approach, any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than removing the class `has-more` when there are no other contents and (yet still) keep on checking its existence on scroll event, why not remove the event handler itself?

That way you have no event handlers and no decision making, until you bind it again, when some other ajax event tells you there are contents available now.

Answer (score 1):

You could set & check a variable in scope. So your example would be something like:

```
!function() {
    var hasMore = true;

    $window.on('scroll', function () {
        var $this = $(this);

        if ($this.scrollTop() == $document.height() - $window.height() && hasMore) {
            // load more content & set hasMore to false if applicable 
        }
    })
}();
```

Only issue here is setting `hasMore` on pageload. Instead of doing what I did (putting it in a self-executing function) you could write `hasMore` in the footer. That's up to you.

This method would avoid overloading a class name as boolean, and would save you the cost (though it's insanely small) of querying the DOM.

Comment: Hmm, we share an object shared between our views and the js very similar to the .NET MVC's ViewBag.. I could set it there..